# Permanent environment variables

Tags: path, cmd, environment

I have a problem assessing my advanced settings of my computer, anytime i get to the properties of my computer it freezes and vanishes, I decided to set my path through the command prompt. Though the lines below works. Its just temporal and the path is unset immediately i close the running command prompt,

```
set path=%path%;C:\python27
```

I am just wondering why my computer's property panel vanishes.

Any others ways to set the environment variables permanent?

Comment: **To See if a Fix is Available** In _Control Panel_ (and select Classic view in the left hand pane) choose _Problem Reports and Solutions_ (type problem in Start's search box), go to _Problem History_, right click your error and choose _Check For Solution_. You may also right click and choose Details for more info. **Post those details here**. The Fault Module Name is the important information. If the problem affects Control Panel press `Winkey + R` and type `wercon` (or type it in a command prompt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\python27"`

Note that u need to close the current cmd window, after executing this command as the changes will reflect in newer instances only.